# How to integrate Google's reCAPTCHA in a React Native app?

Tags: webview, react-native, captcha, recaptcha

I haven't found any React Native library to help with reCAPTCHA, and the only Android library I found is [Android-Lib-reCAPTCHA](https://github.com/ayltai/Android-Lib-reCAPTCHA) but it uses the old API (showing a cypher instead of a checkbox).

I have tried to show the Javascript reCAPTCHA using [react-native-webview-bridge](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge) but I couldn't make it work and it's very slow and unstable. Besides sometimes the captcha needs more space to display pictures when it's not just a checkbox.

Do you know any other way than a WebView? I also checked out native Android captcha systems but they are all too old/complicated (cyphers).

Also, what is the frequency of robots installing apps and subscribing through? Maybe I don't need a captcha but just a secret key/CSRF token?

Answer (score 2):

For the case of web or mobile web application there are a bunch of react wrappers for google captcha. For example [github/react-grecaptcha](https://github.com/evenchange4/react-grecaptcha) worked for me like a charm.

Comment: Then how to test in a native mobile application whether or not a user is human?

Comment: Exactly how do you protect your REST API from bots then? When there are too many request from certain ip/device .. you just show user captcha to filter bots stealing data from your API...

Comment: @Ľubomír That's no longer on the client side. Even if you have a captcha, bots can still find your API URLs and spam it directly. You need to implement some kind of protection in your API, rate limiting for example.

Comment: Thanks for comments, that's right notion. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Alex is this possible to use React component in ReactNative app?

Comment: @CodeBy you can use high level components, however view components has to be rewritten for ReactNative. Here is in more details https://medium.com/@aakashns/sharing-components-between-react-and-react-native-f6ce3713658a

Answer (score 0):

You can try using webview component like this:

first create recaptcha keys at
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

then you create an new component like this:

```
const GetRecaptcha = (props) => {
const onMessage = (data) => {

    console.log('recaptcha', data.nativeEvent.data)
    //here you can put your action to perform(check validation on your server or somthing)
    props.action(data.nativeEvent.data);

};

return <View style={{}}>

    <WebView
        style={{height: 0}}
        onMessage={async (e) => await onMessage(e)}
        containerStyle={{height: 0}}
        source={{
            html: `
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=RECAPTCHA-KEY"></script>
        <script>
        function onLoad(e) {
         
            grecaptcha.ready(function () {
                grecaptcha.execute('RECAPTCHA-KEY', {action: 'submit'}).then((token) => {
                    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(token);
                });
            }) 
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="onLoad()">
        </body>
        </html>`
        , baseUrl: 'your-url',
    }}/>


</View>;
};
```

you could use this component from other component as this example:

```
const action=(token)=>{
   // validate key on server
   if(token){
    //do some action
   }else{
   //do some action
   }
  }
  const App=()=>{
  return <GetRecaptcha action={action}/>
  }
```

Comment: What is the 'your-url' supposed to represent in the case of a WebView in a mobile application, given the host is an app, not a website? I've read the comments that it's the base url for links rendered in the webview, but it doesn't seem like there should be any relative links in this webview. I'm using react-native-recaptcha-that-works, which is a simple shell around the WebView you've shown here, and my reCaptcha calls only generate a token if I use http://127.0.0.1 as my URL, which makes sense on localhost, but I have no idea what to change it to for production.